# What is the cause of the vacuum of space?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, spacetime, vacuum

It seems logical that if space is expanding and also being dragged into black holes throughout the universe, the result would be a vacuum in the universe. Is that a satisfactory explanation of why there is a vacuum in space?

Comment: I fail to  see the logical connection

Answer (score 1):

No.

Interplanetary, interstellar, and intergalactic space is a near vacuum because the matter from the Big Bang, which was originally more-or-less uniformly distributed throughout space, gravitated together into planets, stars, and galaxies due to the Jean's instability.

The radiation from the early universe universe did not collapse along with the matter and is still everywhere, filling the "vacuum" of space with vast numbers of photons. There are around 400 photons in every cubic centimeter of "empty" space!

As far as I know, relativists do not consider black holes to be dragging space into them. They drag in matter and radiation.

Comment: In [Gullstrand-Painlevé coordinates](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gullstrand%E2%80%93Painlev%C3%A9_coordinates), space *is* falling towards massive bodies. See  http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/waterfall.html for a nice popular exposition.

Comment: OK, but if black-holes-dragging-space-into-them is a coordinate-system-dependent concept, it isn't "really" happening, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Yes and no. ;) GR doesn't care what coordinates you use. As long as you remember that space isn't some kind of stuff, the GP waterfall can be a useful model, and less misleading than the old rubber sheet.

Comment: I was going on the assumption that planets and stars are what make up black holes. I wanted to keep the question short. Space is affected when the gravity becomes strong enough to dilate distance and there ultimately is no time or distance in a singularity.